# Combine rows with distinct values into columns

Tags: sql-server

Hello kindly help me with this problem. I have this records in my database:

```
Name    Activity       DateScheduled
Kevin   Meeting        8/1/2016
Kevin   Lunch Meeting  8/1/2016
Kevin   Client Meeting 8/3/2016
Mark    Report         8/2/2016
Mark    Occular        8/4/2016
Mark    Board Meeting  8/2/2016
```

What I want the output to be is like this:

```
Name    8/1/2016        8/2/2016       8/3/2016        8/4/2016
Kevin   Meeting         null           Client Meeting  null
        Lunch Meeting   null           null            null
Mark    null            Report         null            Occular
        null            Board Meeting  null            null
```

So far this is what I have tried but the display is not my desired output:

```
SELECT name
CASE  WHEN (DateScheduled = '08/01/2016') THEN Activity  ELSE  Null END AS [08/01/2016]

,CASE  WHEN (DateScheduled = '08/02/2016')  THEN Activity  ELSE  Null END AS [08/02/2016]

,CASE  WHEN (DateScheduled = '08/03/2016')  THEN Activity  ELSE  Null END AS [08/03/2016]

,CASE  WHEN (DateScheduled = '08/04/2016')  THEN Activity  ELSE  Null END AS [08/04/2016]
From Schedule
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Kevin, what you want to do is Pivot in SQL. May be following SQL tutorial on Pivot tables can help http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please check following [SQL Pivot query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx)

```
select
 *
from (
  select * from EventsTable
) Data
PIVOT (
 MAX(Activity)
 FOR DateScheduled
 IN (
  [20160801],[20160802],[20160803],[20160804]
 )
) PivotTable
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, the answer is incorrect because Each name should list all the Activities under the given dates. I have updated my question with different example to further illustrate the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing dates manually in Pivot query, you can choose to build [dynamic SQL pivot query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-dynamic-pivot-table-example-code.aspx) as shown below

```
DECLARE @dates nvarchar(max)
SELECT @dates =
 STUFF(
 (
  select distinct ',[' + CAST(cast([date] as date) as varchar(10)) + ']'
  FROM [dbo].[DateTable]('20160801','20160831')
  for xml path('')
 ),
 1,1,'')

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = N'
select
 *
from (
  select * from EventsTable
) Data
PIVOT (
 MAX(Activity)
 FOR DateScheduled
 IN (
  ' + @dates + '
 )
) PivotTable 
'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Please note that before you execute above SQL Select statement, you need to create user defined function to [create dates table in SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-dates-table-using-tsql-cte-calendar-table.aspx) . This function enables calendar table dbo.DateTable() between given two dates

Another interesting part of this dynamic SQL pivot is, programmers use [SQL concatenation using XML Path](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/concatenate-using-xml-path.aspx) . So we concatenate all dates seperated by comma and build our @SQL variable. 
At the end we evaluate the @SQL command using sp_ExecuteSQL stored procedure

Output is as follows

[image]